# Prototype to JQuery - how to access originator of event

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, dom-events

I'm coming from a Prototype background and looking into JQuery. I'd like to know the 'right' way to do attach a click event to a bunch of elements, but then know in the event handler which one of my elements was clicked.

I've come up with the following:

```
MYNS.CarouselHelper.prototype.attachImgHandlers = function () {

  $j(".carouselItem").bind("click", this, function(e){ e.data.openCarouselImage(e) });

}
```

I then have the following in my event handler:

```
MYNS.CarouselHelper.prototype.openCarouselImage = function(e) {

    var img = e.currentTarget;
    // Do stuff to the image element

};
```

Is this 'right'? It feels wrong to me as I am used to explicitly passing the element to the event handler in Prototype as I loop through an array of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the callback to the event, you can access the item as `this`. Like so:

```
$('.foo').bind('click', function(e) { // e is the event
    $(this).html('clicked'); // do something to the element, or whatever
});
```